# Annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration error in package info class in Java 8

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, java-8, package-info

I have a package info class, it used to compile in Java 6/7. But in Java 8, I get compilation errors:

*****error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
@NamedNativeQueries({

error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
@SqlResultSetMappings({*****

This is the code:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({

    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "",
        query = "",
        resultSetMapping = "mapping"
    ),
    NamedNativeQuery(
         name = "",
         query = "",
         callable = true,
         readOnly = false,
         resultSetMapping = ""
    )
})

@SqlResultSetMappings({

})

package abc.domain;
import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMappings;
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Additional comments have made more clear what's going wrong here; as a consequence, the nature of this answer has changed somewhat.

It sounds like you switched from Hibernate's own version of [`@NamedNativeQueries`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NamedNativeQuery.html) and company, which you can stick on packages, to the general javax persistence [variant](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQueries.html), which cannot be placed on packages.

You must have removed and re-generated the imports in your attempt to convert this code. Don't do that - remove all those imports and replace them with `import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQueries` and friends instead.

---

For posterity, the original answer, still valid but only in context specifically for `javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries`.

You must be misremembering; it does not [*and never has*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQueries.html) worked on java7 (that's the java7 docs of `amedNativeQueries` - note how it has a `@Target(value=TYPE)` marker, so it cannot be put on a package, and that's the v7 edition of the docs!)

You put such things on a type, for example the top level type. Which means the annotations appear near the top, but after the package statement. Given that you're using them in a `package-info.java` file, they simply cannot appear here (and never could).

[`SqlResultSetMappings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMappings.html) is the same.

There's a small chance that somehow `javac7` didn't actually check the `Target` condition of these annotations. However, that simply means that your code never worked, even if it did compile.

Comment: It compiled, built and worked in Java 6. It compiled and built in Java 7, not sure if it worked. I am trying to upgrade the project from Java 6 to Java 8.

Comment: The annotations do not even make sense on a package. It's hard to fathom would it could even mean.

Comment: How to declare these annotations to make them work for Java 7?

Comment: The annotations seem to be possible as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602397/how-do-i-externalize-named-queries-in-a-hibernate-annotations-app

Comment: Figured it out for you. I thoroughly edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Adding ``@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQueries`` and ``@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery`` to the annotation fixed the annoation error for ``@NamedNativeQueries`` and ``@NamedNativeQuery``. But ``@SqlResultSetMappings`` still throws annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration error.

Comment: Well, you do the work. javax.persistence's version of SqlResultSetMappings __has never been legal on packages__.